# Ubuntu UFW firewall always block port first time

Tags: ssh, firewall, ufw

First time when the system starts ufw blocks all ports that are allowed.

If I disable ufw and enable again, they start to be allowed;

I don't understand the issue, please, help.

See my configuration (see 1982)

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
1982/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
1:79/tcp                   DENY        Anywhere
1:79/udp                   DENY        Anywhere
81:442/tcp                 DENY        Anywhere
81:442/udp                 DENY        Anywhere
444:1981/tcp               DENY        Anywhere
444:1981/udp               DENY        Anywhere
1983:5431/tcp              DENY        Anywhere
1983:5431/udp              DENY        Anywhere
5433:65535/tcp             DENY        Anywhere
5433:65535/udp             DENY        Anywhere
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
5432/udp                   DENY        Anywhere
1982/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1982/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1:79/tcp (v6)              DENY        Anywhere (v6)
1:79/udp (v6)              DENY        Anywhere (v6)
81:442/tcp (v6)            DENY        Anywhere (v6)
81:442/udp (v6)            DENY        Anywhere (v6)
444:1981/tcp (v6)          DENY        Anywhere (v6)
444:1981/udp (v6)          DENY        Anywhere (v6)
1982/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1983:5431/tcp (v6)         DENY        Anywhere (v6)
1983:5431/udp (v6)         DENY        Anywhere (v6)
5433:65535/tcp (v6)        DENY        Anywhere (v6)
5433:65535/udp (v6)        DENY        Anywhere (v6)
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432/udp (v6)              DENY        Anywhere (v6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, ufw reset only didn't worked, I found this answer on ubuntuforums to reset iptables

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1381516

```
 ##
   ## set default policies to let everything in
   ip6tables --policy INPUT   ACCEPT;
   ip6tables --policy OUTPUT  ACCEPT;
   ip6tables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT;

   ##
   ## start fresh
   ip6tables -Z; # zero counters
   ip6tables -F; # flush (delete) rules
   ip6tables -X; # delete all extra chains

# IPv4

   ## 
   ## set default policies to let everything in
   iptables --policy INPUT   ACCEPT;
   iptables --policy OUTPUT  ACCEPT;
   iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT;

   ##
   ## start fresh
   iptables -Z; # zero counters
   iptables -F; # flush (delete) rules
   iptables -X; # delete all extra chains
```

Comment: Your question was about ufw not iptables.

Comment: yes, indeed, but ufw modify iptables, and nothing done at the ufw level woeked, so I was forced to reset all rules and start again

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ssh allowed? Do `sudo ufw allow ssh`. You can also check to make sure ssh is in the app list. Do `sudo ufw app list`.

Also, make sure the open ssh profile is 22 and not 1982. That could be why your being blocked. Check it with `sudo ufw app info OpenSSH`.

If you still are experiencing the same problems, you may want to reset ufw and rebuild it. I would try to narrow it down and isolate any issues one step at a time. Start with ssh first and see if you can get that working. Then proceed to do the others.

So, do `sudo ufw reset` and then `sudo ufw enable`. Then start adding your rules with `sudo ufw allow 1982/tcp` and keep building from there.

Comment: yes OpenSSH is in the list, but I intentional changed the port; also is blocking 80 for http and 5432 for database; but like I said if I disable and enable immediately, everything is working which is strange

Comment: there are any rules, first allow and after deny, or first deny?

Comment: I would rebuild your table with ufw reset and start over, like I said in my answer. Then just add 1982 and see if you can get it working with just one rule.